# Overriding comparison operators in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, operator-overloading

I would like to override >= operator in Groovy, have found [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) page, but I am still not sure how to do it. I have a class Banknote with properties serial and amount and I wish to implement comparison bases on the amount property.

Comment: Do you want to identify `>=` or you also want to intercept `<`, `>` and such?

Comment: I don't need to intercept a specific operator, so overriding all comparison operators is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't override the `>=` operator, you implement `compareTo`:

```java
class Foo implements Comparable {
  int val
  int compareTo(Object o) { return val <=> ((Foo) o).val }
}

f1 = new Foo(val: 5)
f2 = new Foo(val: 10)
println f1 <= f2
=> true
```

Comment: how about:
int compareTo(def o) {val <=> o.val }
?

Comment: @Dan, the `def` in not needed on parameters: `int compareTo(o) {val <=> o.val }` =D

Comment: @Dan Sure, depending on what kind of error you want to get back. I'd generally rather have a class cast issue if I'm comparing specific classes, otherwise I'd compare against an interface, but it's often a matter of preference.